# separate delimiter with 'equals' and 'comma' .NET Visual Basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I need assistance in getting only the phone number and email address as values and save them into the database. Note that they are separated by two delimiters - the equal sign and comma.
Assuming the values below are from a .CSV file

> (phone=544785415, email=world@gmail.com)

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: You could Substring between = and ,

Comment: vb.net has built-in support for parsing a .csv file, use the [TextFieldParser class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 2):

You can first split by `,` then split by `=`

```
Dim str = "(phone=544785415, email=world@gmail.com)"
' removing parenthesis 
str = str.Trim("("c, ")"c)
' splitting by ,
Dim commaSep = str.Split(","c)

For Each v In commaSep
    Dim fieldValue = v.Trim().Split("="c)
    Dim field = fieldValue(0)
    Dim value = fieldValue(1)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", field, value)
Next
```